# Autohotkey 'keydown' upon open a New Form for a Document Set in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-set

I am trying to figure out a way for an autohotkey to fire once a New Document Set Form is opened, and populate the 'Name' (required) field. The hotkey script should only fire when the 'Name' field is blank (hence, in a New Form). It would be as if I were sitting there and placing the cursor in the 'Name' field and manually hitting the (F7) key to populate the 'Name' field.

I have programmed an autohotkey script to generate a random string of numbers and letters. The script is as follows:

```
F7::
    my_array=a,b,9,c,d,8,e,f,7,z
    Sort, my_array, Random D,
    my_string:=RegExReplace(my_array, ",")
    Send %my_string%
Return
```

When I Create a New Document Set, I'd like the following to happen:

1. The New Form opens
2. My autohotkey script runs
3. The 'Name' field is populated

This would be a massive help -- thanks in advance.

**UPDATED CODE (still not working)**
The Document Library doesn't have a 'default New Form', so so I put a Document Library WP (library Name 'Publications') on a page with the script.I'm stuck.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    try {
        var #no idea what goes here = #no idea what goes here ['my_string'];
        SPUtility.GetSPField('FileLeafRef').SetValue(urlValue).MakeReadOnly();
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: If you're on Firefox or Chrome do check out the GreaseMonkey (FF) or TamperMonkey (Chrome) extensions. They allow you to run JavaScript in any page. That's a lot easier to develop and test compared to AutoHotKey (I know.. been there, done that)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working an on-prem server, so I'm limited to IE. I would like to have this feature built into the SharePoint App. I basically want it to hit the F7 key after a New Document Set Form opens. Is this possible?

Comment: AutoHotKey was created for automation. You can wait for a keypress, but it is always going to be a process monitoring your Browser, your SharePoint Add-In will not be aware of its existence. BTW SharePoint works fine in any browser, you only need IE if you want Open With Explorer and other Office integration

Comment: Hmmm...makes sense. Is there anything I can do to fill the 'Name' field with a text string upon opening a New Form? A Workflow won't cut it, because it will only fill the filed after it's saved (and it won't save, because it requires a unique value). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you want, maybe the easiest is:

- Browse to a New Form
- Add `&toolpaneview=2` to the end of the URL and press enter

  more url magic: http://sharethepunto.blogspot.nl/2014/06/sharepoint-url-tricks.html
- The page is now opened in Edit-mode
- Add a Content Editor WebPart **at the bottom of the page** (set the zone in WebPart properties)
- Add the JavaScript required to generate your string and set the field value
- Save the page

Tip: ***One file to rule them all***
Do not put the code inside the CEWP but link to a JS file in any Library.

Comment: Thank you for the link -- many of these are helpful to me on their own. I'm unsure of how to make the string go into the actual Name field upon page load of the New Form for the Document Library. I can populate other fields with existing SP data, but I have no idea how to do this independent script running and then directed to the 'Name' field. Are there any resources you'd recommend? Thanks, as well.

Comment: Attach a script that after pageload sets the value

Comment: I updated the script in the Questions section. If you can help, I'd appreciate it it -- if not, any insight would be great. Appreciate all of your time so far, regardless.

Comment: I have to be blunt.. I fear you're trying to play major league without knowing how to hit the ball.. take it step by step.. first learn jQuery, then mix in SPUtility... First ball practice (and forget about the game):: use jQuery to (after pageload) execute : ``document.getElementById('pageTitle').style.background='red';``

Comment: Fair Point -- I think you're right.